# Access static color from IB

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder

Is there a way to access a UIColor(declared in swift) in IB ? Example I have a shade of purple called primaryPurple. Can I change background color of navigation bar using that variable.

I know this can done by extending UI navigation bar class. I am looking for any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class called 'Universal':

```
//  Universal.swift
struct UniversalStatic {
    static let data = Universal()
}

public class Universal {
let primaryPurple : UIColor = UIColor(red: 148/255, green: 0/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

Within the AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UniversalStatic.data. primaryPurple
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Comment: This works only for navigation bar. But I want a way I can use a single variable across swift code and IB.